# one column table with multiple <th>

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, semantics

I have a simple `table` :

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey
}

th,
td {
  padding: .5rem
}

th {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Feed in Braids</th>
      <td>20 / two braids</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Waves / Curls / Straightening</th>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Hairstyle for special occasions</th>
      <td>45-60</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to squeeze the data in one column, which would probably have to look something like this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

th,
td {
  padding: .5rem
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Feed in Braids</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20 / two braids</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Waves</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Special</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>40 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have doubts if the "squeezed" `table` would be a correct construct, in terms of possibly unclear scope of the headings.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Is is technically correct for a one column table, to have multiple headings (like in the second example)

Comment: From a semantic / accessibility perspective. So you are implying this question can not be answered in an non-opinion based way?

Comment: A one column table is no longer tabular data -- it's a layout table, or at best a list. For making large tables legible on small screens, I prefer using "no more tables" https://codepen.io/sergio_pinna/pen/wWPREd/  The default styling needs some adjustment, but it's a good concept. Better than horizontal scrolling IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning accessibility, a table header (`th`) can only have either "row" or "column" as its *scope*, and this is always valid for the whole row or column. So in this way your "one-column table" doesn't really meet accessibility standards and isn't semantically correct.

But if you have everything in one column, you could as well use **alternating headers** (like h3, h4, h4, whatever) instead of `th` **and paragraphs** (or simply contents following the headers) instead of `td`. And once you are that far, a table itself wouldn't make that much sense – the wparent element might as well be a `div`...

You also might want to consider a **definition list**  instead, maybe (depending on what your actual usecase looks like, or which function it should fulfill): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Or you use **nested tables**, i.e. multiple tables consisting of one `th` and one `td`, nested either in the cells of a larger table (if that semantically makes sense at all) or simply inside a `div` or `section` element.

Comment: I'm was looking for a way to retain the data in a present - tabular way. As I have to  restructure it for smaller screens. One more possible way would be to reshape it visually in CSS, like here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385593/how-to-convert-this-4-column-table-into-single-column-table-but-still-maintaini

Comment: I suppose to have a table like in the example you linked to it would be best (for mobile devices) not to change the structure, but wrap the table in a 100% wide div and allow it to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Didn't wanted to break the text